# VueJS and "vue-markdown", When `rendered` event is triggered the DOM is still not ready

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

I have this:

```
<vue-markdown :source="content" v-on:rendered="afterRenderContent"></vue-markdown>
```

But when the method `afterRenderContent` is triggered the HTML elements are still not there.

I would like to do DOM HTML elements manipulation after the rendering but I can not. What is the proper way to wait until the DOM is ready?

I have tried to create a JSFiddle to reproduce the issue but looks like the CDN library is no loading properly:

- https://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/5wamjxke/

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your afterRenderContent method to the mounted lifecycle hook. You can only manipulate DOM elements after the component has been mounted.

```
mounted() {
    this.afterRenderContent()
}
```

More on lifecycle methods here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram.

I notice you are also using some vanilla javascript, in your js fiddle, refs can be used in vue to access DOM elements in a more intuitive fashion .

```
<template>
    <h1 ref="header-one">Header One</h1>
</template>

// in your component method or mounted hook
mounted() {
    
    // access the header element 
    this.$refs['header-one']
}
```

**EDIT:** On a deeper dive Perhaps this might work, hooking into the mounted lifecycle method from a child component.

```
<vue-markdown :source="content" @hook:mounted="afterRenderContent"</vue-markdown>
```

Decent blog on how to use refs with vue here https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-refs-to-access-your-application-dom-in-vue-js/

Comment: It is not working for me. `mounted` lifecycle method is triggered even before the `vue-markdown` has parsed the Markdown source.

Comment: I just tried hooking into the mounted event from a parent component like this, 

`<vue-markdown :source="content" @hook:mounted="afterRenderContent"</vue-markdown>`

Seems to work for regular components. 

Looking at the documentation  for vue-markdown hooking into the rendered emitted event should also work, still strange it doesn't .

Comment: I see that the `mounted` event is triggered even before the `postrender` event in the `vue-markdown` component. I am still not able to manipulate DOM elements created by the rendering of the Markdown source in the `mounted` event :/